# Firefox 4 submit button problem

Tags: html, button, firefox4

In Firefox 4 when I press submit button nothing happens. The code of button is:

```
<input class="button" type="SUBMIT" value="Login" form="dataForm" name="event_Login">
```

On Firefox 3.6 the button is working OK. Some solution?

Comment: more info please. do you ouse xhtml? html strict? type="submit" works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the problem is with `form="dataForm"`.  When I remove that attribute, the button works fine again in FF4.  The value of the `form` attribute should be the `id` of a form to submit, otherwise the button will do nothing (at least in FF4).  For instance, this button will work:

```
<form id="dataForm">
    <input  ... form="dataForm" />
</form>
```

Comment: I suppose it also helps to set the HTML 5 doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's your problem, but I had a similar one - solution was putting "SUBMIT" in lowercase.

Comment: Tried that.  Doesn't actually make any difference.